# Windows universal app live chart of accelerometer data

Tags: c#, xaml, charts, win-universal-app, accelerometer

I'm writing my first universal windows app and am currently experimenting with the accelerometer. 
Currently I'm displaying it's reading as numbers on the screen but I would like to also show a graph that depicts these values visually. 
I've seen some charting examples online but none that accept a live stream of data and display it as it comes in.

Basically what I want is a graph over the time domain that draws a line which represents the values the accelerometer outputs.

This is my first attempt at windows programming and I'm working with C#.

Is there a 'proper' way to do such a thing? a commonly accepted method?

Comment: OxyPlot should work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/):

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Charting:Chart x:Name="chart1" Grid.Row="0">
            <Charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                                 DependentValuePath ="Accel"
                                 IndependentValuePath ="Timestamp" Margin="0"/>
        </Charting:Chart>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="START" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnStart_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="STOP" Grid.Row="2" Click="btnStop_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MyViewModel vm;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.Stop();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private Timer accelerometer;
    private Random r;

    private ObservableCollection<MyAccelModel> data;
    public ObservableCollection<MyAccelModel> Data { get { return data; } }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        data = new ObservableCollection<MyAccelModel>();
        r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        accelerometer = new Timer(AccelDataCallback, null, 100, 500);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        accelerometer.Dispose();
    }

    private async void AccelDataCallback(object state)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                data.Add(new MyAccelModel { Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Accel = r.NextDouble() });
            });
    }
}
```